# clr() vs. scale in prcomp function r?

Tags: r, pca

I am writing on a script, I haven't initially created. It is for core records. I have a data frame which shows the different elemental compositions in the columns over a given depth (in the first column). I want to perform a PCA with it and I am confused about the standardization method I have to choose.

Has anyone of you used the `clr()` to prepare your data for the `prcomp()`? Or does it adulterate my solutions. I have tried using the `clr()` on the data before using the `prcomp()` function in addition to using the attribute `scale` in `prcomp()`.

```
data_f_clr<- clr(data_f)
data_pca <- prcomp(data_f, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
```

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/prcomp.html

`scale` is described to scale the data, so they have unit variance. Since my data have a very different scale that is what i wanted, I think. The problem is, that I receive a different solution, when I use the code above or when I skip the `clr()` (which makes the more wanted result). But I want to know why is the `clr()` disturbing in that case?

It would be great, if anyone of you could help me with this.

Comment: 1) Which `clr` function are you referring to, as it does not appear in `base? 2) The results are different because the data going in is different. PCA is sensitive to differences in scale which scale/center tries to fix. 3) This question is more about stats/methods than programing, I would recommend posting to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This question is more about stats/methods than programing, I would recommend posting to CrossValidated –     yes, maybe you are right. I just posted it there. thanks for recomending this site.